# Android Kernel Compliation Error

Tags: android, android-ndk, kernel

I'm trying to complie an android kernel to a device.I opened a folder named "Kernel" which is including my source codes. And i opened a folder named "NDK" which is including toolchains.I'm using this codes:

```
cd /home/leonidasturk/Kernel

export CROSS_COMPILE=/home/leonidasturk/NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-

make clean && make mrproper
```

And i get this errors

```
ALPS IF Driver build option : -DACC_10BIT -DMAG_15BIT

/home/leonidasturk/Kernel/drivers/input/misc/alps/Makefile:59: .config: No such file or directory

make[4]: *** No rule to make target `.config'.  Stop.
make[3]: *** [drivers/input/misc/alps] Error 2
make[2]: *** [drivers/input/misc] Error 2
make[1]: *** [drivers/input] Error 2
make: *** [_clean_drivers] Error 2
```

I'ı using ubuntu 14.04 LTS and installed required packages. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing kernel config part- make system does not know which files to include in the build...
Try with:

> make config

If you want to quickly create a default configuration, try with:

> make defconfig